# UIView.drawHierarchy fails under iOS 17

Tags: ios, uiview, pdf-generation, ios-pdfkit, ios17

I have a feature in my app where I export a bunch of images into a PDF. For this, I use

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo
```

and

```
myView.drawHierarchy(in: myView.frame, afterScreenUpdates: true)
```

This worked perfectly fine for several years. And now it has broken with the latest update. Any hints on what could be causing this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now fixed from iOS 17.1 onwards.